# Sum the last five objects of a JSON

Tags: python, json

To access JSON I use:

```
url = f'https:...........'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
graphs = response['graphPoints']
for graph in graphs:
    sum_value = graph['value']
```

This JSON can change size, so the last five `"value"` I'm trying to sum won't always be in the same position, so I can't specify exactly which position:

In this case, the sum would give the result `31`

```
[
  ...
  {'minute': 87, 'value': 4},
  {'minute': 88, 'value': 4},
  {'minute': 89, 'value': 4},
  {'minute': 90, 'value': 4},
  {'minute': 90.5, 'value': 15}
]
```

If I wanted to sum all the 92 `"value"`, I could create a list:

```
List_Of_Values = []
List_Of_Values.append(graph['value'])
```

But in case I will always only need the last 5 `"value"`, how could I do that?

Remembering that this JSON can contain different sizes, so I can't specify in which position the last 5 will be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is simple [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions) with a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation):

```
>>> sum(d["value"] for d in graphs["graphPoints"][-5:])
31
```